# understanding uniform distribution cdf equivalence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

I am confused about the following statement which I read some lecture notes. So the claim is: $Y$ is uniformly distributed in the interval $[0,\alpha]$ and the way the notes proves this is by showing that: $\Pr[Y\leq y]=y/\alpha$ for all $y$. Now, why is showing $\Pr[Y\leq y]=y/\alpha$, equivalent to showing $Y$ is uniform in the interval $[0,\alpha]$. I see if $Y$ is uniform then this statement is true, but not the converse, could someone clarify?

Answer (score 0):

How are you mathematically defining the statement "$Y$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,a]$?"

If you are defining it as $Y$ has the density $$f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{a} \mathbb 1(0 \le y \le a),$$ then we can compute 
$$\begin{align*}
f_Y(y) 
&= \lim_{\Delta y \to 0} \frac{\Pr[Y \le y + \Delta y] - \Pr[Y \le y]}{\Delta y} \\
&= \lim_{\Delta y \to 0} \frac{1}{\Delta y} \left(\frac{y + \Delta y}{a} - \frac{y}{a}\right)\mathbb 1 (0 \le y + \Delta y \le a) \\
&= \lim_{\Delta y \to 0} \frac{1}{a} \mathbb 1 (0 \le y + \Delta y \le a) \\
&= \frac{1}{a} \mathbb 1 (0 \le y \le a),
\end{align*}$$
as claimed.

But if you define it in some other way, then you have to state this definition.  For example, you can say that $Y$ is uniform if for any $0 \le y_1 < y_2 \le a$, $$\Pr[y_1 \le Y \le y_2] = \frac{y_2 - y_1}{a}.$$  This is also an acceptable definition.  It means that the probability that $Y$ lies in some subinterval $[y_1, y_2]$ is proportional to the length of that subinterval, and that the constant of proportionality is independent of the choice of subinterval.

Comment: Thanks! I did mean your former definition. I think my question was more, suppose $f_Y(\leq b)=b/a$ for every $b\in [0,a]$, then why does that imply $f_Y$ is uniform in the interval $[0,a]$. Everything is according to the first definition of yours.